# Bazel create C++ shared library with soname

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, bazel

I would like to create a **shared** c++ library with Bazel using a **soname**.

With `cmake` I could set properties like:

```
set_target_properties(my-library
        PROPERTIES
                SOVERSION 3
                VERSION 3.2.0
        )
```

which would then generate

```
libmy-library.so -> libmy-library.so.3
libmy-library.so.3 -> libmy-library.so.3.2.0
libmy-library.so.3.2.0
```

However in `bazel` documentation I cannot find anything that would allow me to do so easily. I know that I could define the soname and version directly and pass some `linkopts` in the build file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libmy-library.so.3.2.0",
    srcs = ["my-library.cpp", "my-library.h"],
    linkshared = 1,
    linkopts = ["-Wl,-soname,libmy-library.so.3"],
)
```

which does produce **libmy-library.so.3.2.0** with the correct soname, but not the .so file so it would require a whole lot of hacks around to:

- create libmy-library.so.3 symlink
- create libmy-library.so symlink
- create some import rules such that I can build binaries that link with this library.

This does not feel like the right way. What would be the right way to solve such problem?

Comment: I know it's been a while since this was asked. But what is the end result that you are trying to achieve? e.g. Are you attempting to make a deb/rpm/tar?